# C# sql query to add attributes for the elements in xml

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, xml

I want to display the XML file by taking tag from the `XML_TAGS` table, and attributes from the`MAPPED_TAGS_ATTRIBUTES` table - something like `<element attributes></element>`:

```
String sql = "SELECT Dtd_Tag,Dtd_Attribute_Name 
                FROM Xml_Tags,
                     Mapped_Tags_Attributes 
               WHERE Mapped_Tags_Attributes.Pdf_Tag = Xml_Tags.Pdf_Tag 
            ORDER BY Mapped_Tags_Attributes.Pdf_Tag 
             FOR XML AUTO";
```

Comment: i want to display xml file by taking tag from xml tags table and attributes from Mapped_tags Attributes table... something like <element attributes></element>

Comment: Please add the structure of the tables you want to use, some sample data and the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Query:

```
select
    c.CustomerId as "@Id",
    c.AcountNumber as "@AcountNumber"
from Customer c
for xml path('Customer'), root('Customers')
```

Result:

```
<Customers>
   <Customer Id="1" AccountNumber="X120" />
   <Customer Id="2" AccountNumber="X121" />
</Customers>
```

Comment: i want the query to take the elements and attributes from database..how can i do that...

Comment: 1 <Image> mediaobject
1 <b> title
1 <para id =0> para
1 <i> pubdate
1 <para id =1> simpara
1 <para id =2> titleabbrev
1 <para id =3> section
1 <para id =4> sect1
1 <para id =5> sect2
1 <para id =6> sect3
1 <para id =7> glossdef
NULL NULL NULL

Comment: <Image> xlink:actuate onLoad #IMPLIED null
<Image> xml:lang CDATA #IMPLIED null
<Image> xml:base CDATA #IMPLIED null
<Image> remap CDATA #IMPLIED null
<b> xmlns CDATA #FIXED "http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
<b> xlink:actuate none #IMPLIED null
<para id =0> revision CDATA #IMPLIED null
<para id =0> vendor CDATA #IMPLIED null
<para id =0> wordsize CDATA #IMPLIED null
<para id =0> xlink:actuate none #IMPLIED null
<i> xreflabel CDATA #IMPLIED null
<i> revisionflag added #IMPLIED null